# Confusion about the boundary condition of rectangular potential barrier in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, boundary-conditions

In the book Quantum Mechanics by N. Zettili ([page 224, 2nd edittion](http://www.faculty.fairfield.edu/ssawin/QM-Irit/Zettili.pdf)), the potential $V(x)$ is defined as:
$$V(x) = \begin{cases}
    0  & ; \,x \lt 0 \\
    V_0  & ; \,  0 \le  x \le a \\
    0  & ; \, x \gt a \\
\end{cases}$$
For the case $E \gt V_0$, the wave functions in the regions: 
$$\psi(x) = \begin{cases}
    \psi_1(x)=Ae^{ik_1x}+Be^{-ik_1x}  & ; \,x \le 0 \\
    \psi_2(x)=Ce^{ik_2x}+De^{-ik_2x}  & ; \,  0 \lt  x \lt a \\
    \psi_3(x)=Ee^{ik_1x}  & ; \, x \ge a \\
\end{cases}$$

How does the case ($0 \le  x \le a)$ of $V(x)$ correspond to the case ($0 \lt  x \lt a$) of $\psi(x)$?   How is the equality sign moves to the first and third regions?
Why and how does the domain condition change?

Some books like Griffiths and also on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_potential_barrier#Calculation), I don't find any equal sign there.
The three cases are given for: (i) $x \lt 0$ (ii) $0 \lt x \lt a$ (iii) $x>a$.

Don't we need to include $x=0$ and $x=a$ ? If not, then how can be the four boundary conditions applied on the wavefunction $\psi(x)$?
What am I missing? I am really confused.
TIA

Comment: In general one requires the wave function to be continuous everywhere. Hence by gluing the solutions in the different regions together you effectively remove this problem.

Comment: Yes, I know it. But it doesn't clear my confusion.

Comment: It sounds like people were careless about the boundaries. Nothing deep here. Because the solution must be continuous, the functions on both sides of a boundary point give the same value. So it doesn't matter which function you use at the boundary. So people didn't worry about it.

Comment: Can it be written as:
$$V(x) = \begin{cases}
    0  & ; \,x \le 0 \\
    V_0  & ; \,  0 \le  x \le a \\
    0  & ; \, x \ge a \\
\end{cases}
$$

$$\psi(x) = \begin{cases}
    \psi_1(x)=Ae^{ik_1x}+Be^{-ik_1x}  & ; \,x \le 0 \\
    \psi_2(x)=Ce^{ik_2x}+De^{-ik_2x}  & ; \,  0 \le  x \le a \\
    \psi_3(x)=Ee^{ik_1x}  & ; \, x \ge a \\
\end{cases}$$
?

Comment: @raf That's not correct. You're assigning two different values to $V(x)$ both at $x=0$ and $x=a$, in that way it's not a function. You can't have all of the domains be closed, if one is closed the next one should be open.

Comment: In this case, the solution of the Schrödinger equation is not going to depend on the way you choose which of the domains of the definition of $V$ is closed and which is open, you just have to make sure you make it consistent.

Comment: so, these [four situations](https://i.paste.pics/8BJP5.png) are considered the same? @SV

Comment: Strictly speaking no. Example #1 is not consistent in the domains of $\psi$ and $V$. But since $\psi$ is continuous examples 1-3 are physically equivalent. Example #4 is just plain wrong, you discarded the values of the functions at the discontinuity (i.e., the union of the domains is not $\mathbb R$)

Comment: Example #1 was taken from Zettili's book and example #4 from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_potential_barrier#Calculation).
How about [this way](https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node152.html): 
$$V(x) = \begin{cases} 0  & ; \,x \lt 0 \\ V_0  & ; \,  0 \lt  x \lt a \\  0  & ; \, x \gt a \\ \end{cases} \\ \psi(x) = \begin{cases}     \psi_1(x)=Ae^{ik_1x}+Be^{-ik_1x}  & ; \,x \le 0 \\     \psi_2(x)=Ce^{ik_2x}+De^{-ik_2x}  & ; \,  0 \le  x \le a \\     \psi_3(x)=Ee^{ik_1x}  & ; \, x \ge a \\ \end{cases}$$?

Comment: and  
#6 $$V(x) = \begin{cases} 0  & ; \,x \lt 0 \\ V_0  & ; \,  0 \le  x \le a \\  0  & ; \, x \gt a \\
 \end{cases} \\ \psi(x) = \begin{cases}     \psi_1(x)=Ae^{ik_1x}+Be^{-ik_1x}  & ; \,x \le 0 \\ \psi_2(x)=Ce^{ik_2x}+De^{-ik_2x}  & ; \,  0 \le  x \le a \\     
\psi_3(x)=Ee^{ik_1x}  & ; \, x \ge a \\ \end{cases}$$?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/754354/247642, https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/715950/247642

Answer (score 0):

The boundary conditions demand continuity of the wave function and its derivative at the boundary. For example, for $x=0$ we need to have
\begin{equation}
\psi_1(x) = \psi_2(x), \psi_1'(x) = \psi_2'(x).
\end{equation}
This means that both(!!) $\psi_1(x)$ and $\psi_2(x)$ are defined at this point (and equal)!

This is a rather fine point, and the books seem rather sloppy on it, since it doesn't change much in practice.

Comment: So, can it be written as:
$$V(x) = \begin{cases}
    0  & ; \,x \le 0 \\
    V_0  & ; \,  0 \le  x \le a \\
    0  & ; \, x \ge a \\
\end{cases}
$$

$$\psi(x) = \begin{cases}
    \psi_1(x)=Ae^{ik_1x}+Be^{-ik_1x}  & ; \,x \le 0 \\
    \psi_2(x)=Ce^{ik_2x}+De^{-ik_2x}  & ; \,  0 \le  x \le a \\
    \psi_3(x)=Ee^{ik_1x}  & ; \, x \ge a \\
\end{cases}$$
?

Comment: The potential should not have the overlapping conditions (otherwise $V_0$ has to be 0).

Comment: @NDewolf I agree.

Comment: @raf For piece-wise functions you really should only have one condition for each x value

Comment: At which region/s should be the x=0 and x=a included for $V(x)$ and $\psi(x)$?

Comment: @AaronStevens, then how we write $\psi_1(0)=\psi_2(0)$ ?

Comment: @raf $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ can be defined for all $x$ technically as functions. But when you explicitly write out a piece-wise function you need to make sure only one choice goes to each $x$ value

Comment: @raf It won't really matter for the final solution. Aaron has a point that, once you use strict inequalities in the definition of the potential you should have only one wave function there - which is the opposite of my answer. It is a bit of a paradox, but it has to do with the fact that such rectangular barriers do not exist in real world.